# MySQL: Is it possible to make a foreign key to two different table-columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table (a) which should have a column "user_id", which is a foreign key of some other table (b) OR (c). 
So wether it points to table b or c (only one, not both).

Is this even possible in MySQL? Best thing I can come up with is following (but as you can see, I have "user_id" twice in my "a"-table, which is not very nice, since one of the two values will always be empty.

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: why not? as long as you are using different keys, you can

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please take a look at the attached image above. The question: Is it possible to merge "user_id_a" and "user_id_b" to one column/field of the table "tbl_a"?

Comment: Nope. That's against the ACID. Actually, you have to keep it the way you draw

Comment: you want `xor` operator b or c but not both.

Comment: if you have this urge to point to 2 different tables it may suggest that your design needs more thinking in the first place. For example if your user_id points to dead_users or live_users tables it actually can be rewritten to point to users table where dead/alive is a parameter.

Comment: In light of the answer provided using 'check constraints'... maybe interesting? [New and old ways to emulate CHECK constraints, DOMAIN](http://mysqlserverteam.com/new-and-old-ways-to-emulate-check-constraints-domain/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is called Polymorphic Associations and you cannot enforce it using  MySql foreign key constraints.

in order to have either userId_a null or user_id_b null you can create a check constraint

```
CONSTRAINT CHECK (user_id_a IS NOT NULL OR user_id_b IS NOT NULL)
```